# How to replace a character in a string using nunjucks

Tags: nunjucks

I am trying to remove some characters from a string in a nunjucks template file. The string that I am trying to manipulate is:

```
"swatch_dark_&_stormy"
```

Is there a simple way to remove the `&` without having to create a filter method? I know I can do this with a filter, but I am hoping there is a built in method that I could use instead.

Macro implementation so far:

```
{% macro filterSwatchClass(swatchCSSClassName) %}
    {%set cssClassName = swatchCSSClassName | cleanCSSClassName%}
    {{"swatch_"+cssClassName}}
{% endmacro %}
```

Filter that does the job:

```
env.addFilter('cleanCSSClassName', function(string){
        return string.replace(/&/g,"").replace(/__/g,"_");
    })
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Any code samples?

Comment: just added the basic macro that I am trying to add. I just want to display this class name without ```&``` symbols.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
{% macro filterSwatchClass(swatchCSSClassName) %}
    {%set cssClassName = swatchCSSClassName | cleanCSSClassName %}
    {{"swatch_"+cssClassName | replace("&", "")}}
{% endmacro %}
```

See [replace](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html#replace) on nunjucks docs for more info.

Comment: ```{% macro filterSwatchClass(swatchCSSClassName) %}
    {%set cssClassName = swatchCSSClassName | replace("_&", "")%}
    {{"swatch_"+cssClassName }}
{% endmacro %}``` - This is all I needed the entire time